Adding 1 million torque to a normal cube won't make it rotate extremely fast?
In Unity, I have a normal cube with a rigidbody component. I'm listening to keyboard input and calling AddTorque with extremely high values when a key is pressed. My goal is to make a merry-go round type of thing, that the player can repeatedly increase the speed of. The current problem is that I cannot achieve a high enough speed for the rotation. Even with 1 million torque on the y-axis applied, it will look slow. It doesn't look like the really fast rotation of a merry go round.
Here's a video showing it:
https://imgur.com/a/DKaJIin


By default, Unity Rigidbodies have a maximum angular velocity to avoid numerical instability. You can adjust this with Rigidbody.maxAngularVelocity.

Couldn't this also happen when an object rotates like exactly ½ (180°) or 1 radian (360°) in one frame?

@CheckerT Yes, that is a good point! Kypoa said it "look[s] slow", rather than not rotating at all, but that could also be caused by rotating slightly more than 180° or 360°.
